# Data Based and System Security

Tags: security

Over the last year or so, ever since I started messing around with the blockchain protocol, I my system, database, seems to have gotten hacked time and time again.

I have learned a great deal with regards to computing, cloud networking, and development over the last year, whereas, I am hoping to move forward, grow, and become a global gaming and education providing organization within the blockchain. However, it is real trying and rather complicated to do so when I cannot seem to keep my data based or system stable and/or secure.

Might I receive some assistance and/or a sense of direction as to an honest and trustworthy fix to my security delema, so I can get launched and be a benefit to the community. Please Help!!!!